# Returning a specialized implementation of a generic interface from a generic function without "unchecked" warning

Tags: java, generics

If I write this function:

```
static <T> T getDefaultValue(Class<T> tClass) {
    if(tClass == Integer.class) // or isAssignableFrom
        return (T)Integer.valueOf(0);
    ...
}
```

I get the warning `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Integer to T`, because generics are erased. I can get around it by using `Class.cast`:

```
static <T> T getDefaultValue(Class<T> tClass) {
    if(tClass == Integer.class)
        return tClass.cast(Integer.valueOf(0));
    ...
}
```

But I can't find a way to return a generic type based on the function's generic argument:

```
interface Thing<T> {...}
class ThingForInteger implements Thing<Integer> {...}
static <T> Thing<T> getThing(Class<T> tClass) {
    if(tClass == Integer.class)
        return [what?](new ThingForInteger());
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this, other than the cast that causes the warning?

(Also, is there a way to make a `Map<Class<?>, Thing<[class from key]>>` and get implementations from it without having to suppress the warning?)

Comment: Both are impossible.  Generic typing is erased at runtime, so there is no `List<String>.class`, for example, only `List.class`.

Comment: @VGR I'm asking for a way to provide the information at compile time in a way that satisfies the compiler to not give a warning. That doesn't necessarily mean using a `Thing<T>.class`. [Really, the compiler _should_ be smart enough to not give the warning anyway, since the return statement is guarded by a condition requiring a Class<T> to be equal to a Class<Integer>]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is enough to have no warnings:

```
static <T> Thing<T> getThing(Class<T> tClass) {
    if (tClass == Integer.class) {
        return (Thing) new ThingForInteger();
    }
    ...
```